# Fluentd - Json within the log field is enclosed by double quotes

Tags: fluentd

We have a formatting issue with logs forwarded through fluentd. The issue is that backslash is getting added preceding all double quotes.

Example -

```
2022-02-14T10:17:46+13:00     myapp            {"log":"{\"name\":\"contents\",\"hostname\":\"vcr-amyapp1-yyut-4uh57vb-rr73g\",\"pid\":876265,\"level\":20,\"req_id\":\"1644787066643:vcr-myapp1-03-e263f-v4.0.5:876265:kwljxg59:30317\",\"data\":{\"method\":\"get\",\"url\":\"/api/content/heartbeat\",\"agent\":\"Go-http-client/1.1\"},\"msg\":\"\",\"time\":\"2022-02-13T21:17:46.644Z\",\"v\":0}","container_name":"vcr-myapp1-03-e263f"}
```

The backslashes are invalidating everything within the log json field. That is, it treats the log field as a string instead of json. We need fields within log json field to also be valid json.

What should be changed within fluentd to not add backslashes? I've spent a week now digging into this & still not able to  find anything helpful.

I would truly appreciate any help please.

Current fluentd config file below -

```
<system>
  workers 1
</system>

<source>
  @type  forward
  @id    input1
  @label @mainstream
  port  24224
</source>

# Used for docker health check: healthcheck http://localhost:5000/healthcheck?json=%7B%22log%22%3A+%22health+check%22%7D
# The query parameter in the URL defines a URL-encoded JSON object that looks like this:
# {"log": "health check"}
# The container health check inputs a log message of “health check”. While the query parameter in the URL defines the log message, the path, which is /healthcheck, sets the tag for the log message. In Fluentd, log messages are tagged, which allows them to be routed to different destinations.
<source>
  @type http
  port 5000
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

# records sent for health checking won't be forwarded anywhere
<match health*>
  @type null
</match>

<label @mainstream>
  <filter **>
    @type record_modifier
    remove_keys container_id,source
  </filter>
  <match **>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type file
      @id   output1
      path         /fluentd/log/data.*.log
      symlink_path /fluentd/log/data.log
      append       true
      time_slice_format %Y%m%d
      time_slice_wait   10m
      time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
    </store>
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host {{ env "efk__elasticsearch_host" }}
      port {{ env "efk__elasticsearch_port" }}
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix fluentd
      logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
      include_tag_key true
      type_name access_log
      tag_key @log_name
      flush_interval 1s
    </store>
{{ if eq (env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_enabled") "true" }}
    <store>
      @type splunk_hec
      protocol {{ env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_protocol" }}
      hec_host {{ env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_host" }}
      hec_port {{ env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_port" }}
      {{ if env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_token" | regexMatch "^secret/.*" -}}
      hec_token {{ with printf "%s" (env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_token") | secret }}{{ .Data.value }}{{ end }}
      {{ else -}}
      hec_token {{ env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_token" }}
      {{ end }}
      sourcetype ${tag}
    </store>
{{ end }}
  </match>
</label>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant fluentd configuration in your question.

Comment: Hello@Azeem - Many thanks for offering to help. I've updated the question with the config file contents

Comment: Hi! You're welcome! Looks like the JSON parsing is missing. You can add that with parser plugin and configure it for JSON. See: https://docs.fluentd.org/parser

Comment: THank you @Azeem I'm a first time user of fluented. I've inherited this from a resource that moved on. I'm struggling heaps to work out where to add this config. Please could you help with some pointers? I'm not able to work out where in the config file should I add the json parser

Comment: Right. Sure, no worries. I'd suggest to spend some time on the docs (https://docs.fluentd.org/). On the left side, you can start with Overview (Lifecycle of an event), Configuration, and then go to the plugins that you're using. Some are part of the fluentd itself, some are not. You can proceed accordingly. Hint: You can add parser for input plugins if supported, or add a filter plugin that supports the parser.

Comment: Thanks a ton for leading me on the right path @Azeem. I can't thank you enough for this.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Glad you were able to figure it out. Apart from that, I see that you're using Helm to fetch values from env vars, right? Just curious, why are you not using ConfigMap for this and updating default values from `values.yaml` or a custom `.values.yaml` file?

Comment: yeah , we use consul templating a lot :) It's just how it's been done over the years & I've taken over the project for the last few weeks. My role is to migrate things off all of this & user terraform primarily for everything. lol. It's another extreme.

Comment: Right. More props to you! Hope you'll figure it all out with time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer in case this helps someone

Had to add a few things to get this to work.

The filter section needed modification as follows

```
  <filter **>
    @type record_modifier
    remove_keys "container_id,source"
    @type parser
    key_name log
    hash_value_field log
    <parse>
      @type json
    </parse>
  </filter>
```

Complete config below -

```
<system>
  workers 1
</system>

<source>
  @type  forward
  @id    input1
  @label @mainstream
  port  24224
</source>

# Used for docker health check: healthcheck http://localhost:5000/healthcheck?json=%7B%22log%22%3A+%22health+check%22%7D
# The query parameter in the URL defines a URL-encoded JSON object that looks like this:
# {"log": "health check"}
# The container health check inputs a log message of “health check”. While the query parameter in the URL defines the log message, the path, which is /healthcheck, sets the tag for the log message. In Fluentd, log messages are tagged, which allows them to be routed to different destinations.
<source>
  @type http
  port 5000
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

# records sent for health checking won't be forwarded anywhere
<match health*>
  @type null
</match>

<label @mainstream>
  <filter **>
    @type record_modifier
    remove_keys "container_id,source"
    @type parser
    key_name log
    hash_value_field log
    <parse>
      @type json
    </parse>
  </filter>
  <match **>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type file
      @id   output1
      path         /fluentd/log/data.*.log
      symlink_path /fluentd/log/data.log
      append       true
      time_slice_format %Y%m%d
      time_slice_wait   10m
      time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
    </store>
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host {{ env "efk__elasticsearch_host" }}
      port {{ env "efk__elasticsearch_port" }}
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix fluentd
      logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
      include_tag_key true
      type_name access_log
      tag_key @log_name
      flush_interval 1s
    </store>
{{ if eq (env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_enabled") "true" }}
    <store>
      @type splunk_hec
      protocol {{ env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_protocol" }}
      hec_host {{ env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_host" }}
      hec_port {{ env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_port" }}
      {{ if env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_token" | regexMatch "^secret/.*" -}}
      hec_token {{ with printf "%s" (env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_token") | secret }}{{ .Data.value }}{{ end }}
      {{ else -}}
      hec_token {{ env "efk__fluent_splunk_hec_token" }}
      {{ end }}
      sourcetype ${tag}
    </store>
{{ end }}
  </match>
</label>
```